# Display image when ads content is removed

Tags: javascript, css, image, ads

I placed a piece of ads code in a div and at the bottom of page, I have javascript code that checks for the offsetHeight size of the div. If "0" is returned, I could safely assume that the ads has been chewed by ad blockers

What I'm trying to do is, I want an image to appear in the spot where the ads was supposed to be showing when the ads was blocked.

Any idea how to do this?

Edit: Forgot to show the codes

```
<div id="div_bleh">
ads goes here
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function check_blehsize()
{
    if (document.getElementById("div_bleh").offsetHeight == 0)
        // do stuff
}
window.onload = check_blehsize;
</script>
```

Comment: where is the problem? do you ask how to insert an image into this field? why the ad should be removed? are you giving the possibility? Why you dont overlay your adds over an other div, where the image, or text is already the whole time, i saw this method on some big pages

Comment: Just edited my question to make it more clearer

Comment: If the user wants to block ur ad, and if u still want to show the ad, wont they be more pissed?

Comment: Kasturi, I think you misunderstood my intention. The image actually isn't an ads but just an image with a little pledge message.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is some ad-blocker can also add custom url to the black list also so they can still end up blocking the image under the ad anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example which I tested against a very common ad blocker - Firefox's [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) (using the EasyList filter):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/umuqa4) ([edit](http://jsbin.com/umuqa4/edit))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.innocent-class {
    background: url(http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png);
    width: 240px;
    height: 400px
}


.justForTesting, .advertise_ads {
    width: 240px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #fff
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="innocent-class"> <!-- just don't call it "advertContainer" :) -->
    <div class="advertise_ads justForTesting">
        advert here!
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When Adblock Plus finds an element with a class (for example) `.advertise_ads`, it will hide that element.

If it does, the "please don't block my ads!" `background-image` (in this case, the Google logo) from the parent element will be visible.

If the advert isn't blocked, the advert will cover the replacement image.

Try changing `advertise_ads` to something else such as `sdpfjsdfjp`, and the advert will be visible.

I imagine this technique will also work with most other ad blockers.

Comment: this example works perfectly but after you change advertise_ads class to other name, adblock would only chew up the ads script, not the entire section that holds the ads so you won't see the image underneath the white background.

Comment: @Flint: The white background is only there for testing, because there is no actual advert. If this was on a real site there would be an advert there instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you said but what I meant in my comment above is: "Try changing advertise_ads to something else such as sdpfjsdfjp, and the advert will be visible." Nope. The ads is still blocked by adblock but the background image is not showing.

Comment: @Flint: There's a lot of confusion going on between us because I'm not using an actual advert on my test page. Changing the class name is only going to help in my example. Adblock will still block the advert on your actual page because it's not blocking it off the class name - it's blocking it based on the fact it's coming from `http://LOAD-AN-ADVERT.com`. Combining the HTML in your question with the idea behind my answer: `<div id="parent" style="background: url(http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png)"><div id="div_bleh">ads goes here</div></div>` might work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the size of the adverts you will be displayed, which normally you do.

```
<div class="advert">
    <!-- Adverts go here -->
</div>

.advert {
    background-image: url(blah);
    width: 120px;
    height: 250px;
}

.advert > * {
    background-color: white;
}
```

When the advert gets chewed up by an ad blocker wouldn't this content show instead. Just an idea, I've never personally tried to get around an ad blocker.

Comment: This partially works if the div contain text ads. The background image behind the ads will be visible all the time regardless the ads is blocked or not, unless the ads is an image that nicely fill up the div space.

Comment: close but you could see the background image splashes on your page for a short moment when the ads is loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to that div with javascript(jquery in example below),
for example,

```
adContainer = $(".ad-container");
if ( $(".ad-container").height() == 0 ) {
  adContainer.addClass("no-ads");
}
```

and the css will be

```
.no-ads {
  background: url(the_picture.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
  width: ?px;
  height: ?px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm injecting a class, interesting :) Can you show how to do this without jquery?